# Referencing specific property of YAML anchor

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

I am trying to create a template that consists of a single, human-readable file of data values that will be used to populate several source files. Right now, I'm using YAML and a short Python script with Jinja2 to insert the YAML values into template source files, but it's important that the names of how these things are used be preserved, as there are hundreds of parameters that have complex interrelationships.

I'm trying to reference the same data value in multiple places under different names, and trying to use YAML anchors and aliases to do so.

Basically I want this:

```
compute:
  gpus: 4
  cpus: 120
  mem: 900Gi

torchrun:
  nproc_per_node: [compute.gpus]
  ...

resource_requests:
  gpus: [compute.gpus]
  ...
```

I've tried this:

```
compute: &compute
  gpus: 4

torchrun:
  nproc_per_node: *compute.gpus
```

...but apparently it isn't valid syntax in PyYAML, and I've seen conflicting things online as to whether it's valid YAML at all.

The end result will be multiple files, for example:

resources.py:

```
@task(
   gpus = {{ resource_requests.gpus }}
)
def my_task():
  ...
```

and run.sh:

```
torchrun --nproc_per_node={{ torchrun.nproc_per_node }} ...
```

I am aware that with Jinja2 I could simply reuse `compute.gpu` in the templates for both files, but I want to keep the names consistent so that it's easier to reason about what the template values are actually doing (again, there are dozens of such values that get used in different places but must be consistent).

Comment: This YAML file is for data to render a bunch of templates with Jinja2--thought I mentioned it but I guess I deleted that bit. I'd rather keep this kind of logic out of the Python code though. Let me update my question, maybe there's a better way to use jinja2 than what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot is a normal character that can be part of an anchor/alias You [can use](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#ns-anchor-char) all printable non-whitespace
characters, except the flow indicators ( `,[]{}`  ), in an anchor.

So if you
`*compute.gpus` in your YAML document, it has to be preceded by an anchor `&compute.gpus`.

You should always refer to the YAML 1.2 spec as to what is valid YAML, and not rely on what PyYAML can, or cannot, parse, as it only supports a subset of the YAML 1.1 specification (outdated in 2009).

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
compute:
  gpus: &compute.gpus 4

torchrun:
  nproc_per_node: *compute.gpus
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data['torchrun']['nproc_per_node'])
```

which prints:

```
4
```

Comment: This is great (upvoted), however if the eventual consumer of the markup uses PyYAML when loading, then it _is_ desirable to serialize in a way that the loader will understand (and what YAML 1.2 can do is somewhat a moot point). I wouldn't want to have to monkeypatch a different loader into some 3rd-party code unless absolutely necessary. In that case, it may be pragmatic to just name the anchor as `&compute_gpus` (which PyYAML will understand).

Comment: @wim My reference to PyYAML was based on the OP potentially using it to determine if something is valid YAML or not. AFAICT the `yaml_str`  is valid YAML 1.2 and YAML 1.1, and I am pretty sure that it loads with PyYAML (but have not tried0. That the OPs YAML wouldn't load is because of the alias not being proceded by the corresponding anchor, which in turn was based (I assumed) on the misunderstanding that the dot characters was special in the alias.